# How can I protect streaming media?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, mp3, audio-streaming, rtmp

How can I stream MP3 files and best minimize the risk of someone ripping them? I'm using RTMP via CloudFront right now, but `rtmpdump` is virtually `cp` for RTMP streams.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to stop someone from ripping your stream, or even reasonably prevent it.  Even if you somehow keep your stream from being ripped directly, it's simple to digitally record the audio being output by the player.

What you can do is structure your content in such a way that it isn't as useful for ripping.  For instance, if you have an internet radio station that primarily plays music content, fading from one track or the other often discourages folks, as they cannot cleanly record an entire song.

There are also solutions for watermarking audio content.  The watermark is inaudible.  If the content turns up somewhere else later, you can use the tool to determine if it came from your station.  If you could set up watermarking per-connection, you can determine the IP address it came from.  This is very expensive though... not feasible.

I think you'll find that none of this is worth doing, in most cases.  Almost nobody will rip your stream, and it isn't worth the effort to prevent them from doing so, as it isn't possible to completely prevent.